# "Cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java

Trying to create a new instance of an object. I want to create a new film and have it displayed in an arraylist.

So I have two classes.

Class 1

```
public class Films {

//Film Attributes
private String title, studio, director;
private int release, duration, rating;


//default constructor
public Films(){
    title = null;
    studio = null;
    director = null;
    release = 0;
    duration = 0;
    rating = 0;
}

//Start of Film method
public void setFilms(String title, String studio, String director, 
                  int release, int duration, int rating) 
{
    this.title = title;
    this.studio = studio;
    this.director = director;
    this.release = release;
    this. duration = duration;
    this.rating = rating;
}//end of Film method

//Start of getString method
public String getString(){
    return "\nTitle: " + title + "\nRelease: " + release + "\nDuration: " + duration
            + "\nStudio: " + studio + "\nDirector: " + director + "\nRating: " + rating
            + "\n";
}//end of getString method
```

}

and class 2

```
    //start of createFilm() method
private static void createFilm(){

    Films newfilm = new Films(); //create a new instance of a film object

    System.out.println("Film Title: ");
    String title = in.next();

    System.out.println("Release Date: ");
    int release = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Duration: ");
    int duration = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Studio: ");
    String studio = in.next();

    System.out.println("Director: ");
    String director = in.next();

    System.out.println("Rating: ");
    int rating = in.nextInt();

    newfilm.setFilms(title, release, duration, studio, director, rating);
    myfilms.add(newfilm);
}
```

}

I only included the method which i am having trouble with in class 2. Basically the trouble im having is in class 2, the line;

```
Films newfilm = new Films(); //create a new instance of a film object
```

is telling me  'Films cannot be resolved to a type' x2. So both 'Films'.

I imagine its something very stupid and silly that i've overlooked, assumed or missed out but I cant figure out what the problem is.

This is my first post on this subject as you can probably tell so im sorry if i've missed out valuable and key information and parts of the code. I'm new to programming.

Comment: Did you import `Films` in class 2 ?

Comment: Sounds like an import issue, and also as a sidenote, in your constructor for the `Films` class there is no need to set those variables to `null` they are already `null` at that point.

Comment: @Berger, if it's in the same package it doesn't need to be imported.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @px06 There's nothing wrong with explicitly initializing field values.

Comment: @RealSkeptic : I must have missed the part stating that they were in the same package.

Comment: Can you show `package` declaration of both classes?

Comment: @m0skit0 "There is no need"

Comment: @Berger since the user did not give any of the class headers or the information required, assuming that they were in different packages would be jumping to conclusions. Especially given that beginners ofter write classes in the default package.

Comment: Show the whole files, for all we know `Films` is a nested class.

Comment: @Berger I think you might be right, on the project explorer they are in seperate packages. I didnt even notice that. I'm using eclipse.

Comment: @weston see reply to berger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an import issue you need to add `import` statement. Here is an example:

Notice first line `package com.ura.stam.com.ura.stammm`; it is basically a place where your class is placed

```java
package com.ura.stam.com.ura.stammm;

public class MyFilms {

    public MyFilms(){
        System.out.println("Callin constructor of films class");
    }
}
```

Now look how I import it to other class
Notice the second line `import com.ura.stam.com.ura.stammm.MyFilms;` it tells the compile to bring this class to `MyTestClass`

```java
package com.ura.stam.com.ura.sdss;

import com.ura.stam.com.ura.stammm.MyFilms;

public class MyTestClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFilms myFilms = new MyFilms();
    }
}
```